# Backbone Router Issue - Will not load specific action when accessed through the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, router

Can someone look at the code below and let me know why when accessing domain.com/#issue/1 it shows the default action which is the list instead? but when clicking on of the click elements and the url changes to #issue/1 it actually works.

```
// Destroy Views
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
    console.log('Closing view ' + this);
    if (this.beforeClose) {
        this.beforeClose();
    }
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
};

// Backbone Router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize:function () {
        $('#header').html(new HeaderView().render().el);
    },

    routes:{
        "issue/add":"addIssue",
        "issue/:id":"viewIssue",
        "":"list",
    },

    list:function () {
        this.before(function () {
            console.log('test');
            this.issueList = new IssueCollection();
            this.issueListView = new IssueListView({model:this.issueList});
            this.issueList.fetch();
            app.showView('#content', new IssueListView({model:this.issueList}));
        });
    },

    viewIssue:function (id) {
        console.log(id, app.issueList);
        this.before(function () {
            var issue = app.issueList.get(id);
            app.showView('#content', new IssueView({model:issue}));
        });
    },

    addIssue:function () {
        this.before(function () {
            app.showView('#content', new IssueView({model:new Issue()}));
        });
    },

    showView:function (selector, view) {
        if (this.currentView)
            this.currentView.close();
        $(selector).html(view.render().el);
        this.currentView = view;
        return view;
    },

    before:function (callback) {
        if (this.issueList) {
            if (callback) callback();
        } else {
            this.issueList = new IssueCollection();
            this.issueListView = new IssueListView({model:this.issueList});
            this.issueList.fetch();
            $('#content').html(this.issueListView.render().el);
        }
    }

});

tpl.loadTemplates(['header', 'issue-details', 'issue-item', 'issues-list'], function () {
    app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: To determine issues with routing, I usually put a break point in the list function, check the call stack and locate where Backbone is determining the routes. You can look to see what is being passed in that may cause an issue in your routing. The routing part of Backbone is very simple to figure it out, there is a regex expression that is matching the route. The first thing you need to determine is what was passed in and maybe it is different than what you are expecting. I had an issue where I was changing the url via navigate but my click event was sending # so both routes fired.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the way you are loading the router with `tpl.loadTemplates()`. I've recreated the issue on jsfiddle and the problem goes away when you go to the show url:

http://jsfiddle.net/HXE7K/

Working Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/HXE7K/show/
- http://jsfiddle.net/HXE7K/show/#issue/1
- http://jsfiddle.net/HXE7K/show/#issue/add

Comment: Thank You. But i still not sure why the loadTemplates will mess it up. That's a function that i came across reading this blog:  http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app/  not sure why this breaks it though.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by doing the following:

It appears that the tpl.loadTemplates had nothing to do with it but the way the .before function is being executed with the callback.

```
// Destroy Views
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
    console.log('Closing view ' + this);
    if (this.beforeClose) {
        this.beforeClose();
    }
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
};

// Backbone Router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize:function () {


        $('#header').html(new HeaderView().render().el);
    },

    routes:{
        "issue/add":"addIssue",
        "issue/:id":"viewIssue",
        "":"list",
    },

    list:function () {
        console.log('List Route');
        this.before(function () {
            this.issueList = new IssueCollection();
            this.issueListView = new IssueListView({model:this.issueList});
            this.issueList.fetch();
            app.showView('#content', new IssueListView({model:this.issueList}));
        });
    },

    viewIssue:function (id) {
        console.log('View Issue Route ' + id);
        this.before(function () {
            var issue = app.issueList.get(id);
            app.showView('#content', new IssueView({model:issue}));
        });
    },

    addIssue:function () {
        console.log('Add Issue Route');
        this.before(function () {
            app.showView('#content', new IssueView({model:new Issue()}));
        });
    },

    showView:function (selector, view) {
        if (this.currentView)
            this.currentView.close();
        $(selector).html(view.render().el);
        this.currentView = view;
        return view;
    },

    before:function (callback) {
        if(!this.issueList) {
            this.issueList = new IssueCollection();
            this.issueListView = new IssueListView({model:this.issueList});
            this.issueList.fetch({
                success: function(coll, resp) {
                  if(callback) {
                    callback();
                  }
                }});
        } else {
            if(callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    }

});

tpl.loadTemplates(['header', 'issue-details', 'issue-item', 'issues-list'], function () {
    app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```